# Testing EJB Remote Interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, ejb

I am trying to test my ejb remote interfaces using junit. How can I inject the EJB into my test, since this is done outside of the scope of the ejb container?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I inject the EJB into my test?

You have [two](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#gipiu) possibilities:

1. get the ejb reference through the JNDI service. I don't know if you
   are familiar with this service but basically you need to
   instantiate an InitialContext object and perform a JNDI lookup that
   gets the ejb reference.
2. execute the client code inside an [Application Client Container](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaku.html).
   This allow you to inject the ejb reference using the @EJB annotation
   in your test code.

Maybe this clarification is not necessary, but note that in both cases you will get an EJB reference, therefore, when the test executes the server need to be running and the EJB deployed.

It's hard to provide some [example code](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/11/simple-ejb-3-on-jboss-application.html) because the InitialContext configuration and JNDI binding name are vendor-dependet.

Also, take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090947/how-to-easily-test-a-ejb-using-junit)  which provides several alternatives about how to test your Ejbs.