# Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory

Tags: java, maven, ejb

Here this my code:

SpeakerRemote.java

```
package test;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface SpeakerRemote {
    String sayAPhrase( String phrase );
}
```

---

SpeakerBean.java

```
package test;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class SpeakerBean implements SpeakerRemote {
    @Override
    public String sayAPhrase( String phrase ){
         return "Speaker Service:\t" + phrase;
    }
}
```

---

I assembled it with maven. Here I show you invoking part:

Invoker.java

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Invoker {
    public static InitialContext getContext() throws NamingException {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" );
        properties.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099" );
        return new InitialContext( properties );
    }
}
```

---

Main.java

```
import test.SpeakerRemote;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Main {
    public static void main( String... args ) {
        try {
            InitialContext context = Invoker.getContext();
            SpeakerRemote speaker = ( SpeakerRemote ) context.lookup( "SpeakerBean/remote" );
            System.out.println( speaker.sayAPhrase( "Hello, World!" ) );
        }
        catch ( NamingException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Having started this app I received this exception:

"Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]"

Please help me, because I really need to understand it!

P.S. I use jboss 7.1.1 Final + EJB 3.1 + Maven 3.1.1 + Java 1.7 + Win7

Comment: no. tell me how can I observe it

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. I have Jboss on my machine. I have access to any directory. Just tell me, what I shall do)

Comment: The exception message is pretty neat, I think. "Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory". Are you sure that you have the required jar in the classpath?

Comment: First find out which jar the class comes from and then make sure when you run application, the jar is in the classpath. Also, all the code you posted are not even relevant. You need to check your classpath setting.

Comment: Let me describe what I have done. I put SpeakerRemote.java and SpeakerBean.java into jar-file using maven assembling and deployed it on Jboss. Then I made client-app (Main.java + Invoke.java) and  add jar-file into lib-dir.

Comment: Hi. Set JNDI name to you ejb.Remote object and deploy the latest pkg into server. then lookup ejb remote object using that JNDI name.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Sukkoor, I am actually beginner in EJB. Please, tell me ho I can set JNDI name? Shall I use the "Name" annotation to my remote interface?

Answer (score 4):

Read this documentation for JBoss 7.1

[Remote EJB invocations via JNDI - EJB client API or remote-naming project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project)

Add to classpath jboss-client.jar from $JBOSS_HOME/bin/client

#### Invoker.java

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
// username
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
// password
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
// This is an important property to set if you want to do EJB invocations via the remote-naming project
properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
// create a context passing these properties
return new InitialContext(properties);
```

#### Main.java

```
// lookup the bean    
SpeakerRemote speaker = (SpeakerRemote) context.lookup("myapp/myejbmodule/SpeakerBean!test.SpeakerRemote);
System.out.println( speaker.sayAPhrase( "Hello, World!" ) )
```

### Other approach: [EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

Add to classpath file jboss-ejb-client.properties

#### jboss-ejb-client

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
#if you test on local machine
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER

remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=127.0.0.1
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.username=user
remote.connection.default.password=password
```

#### Invoker.java

```
final Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
return new InitialContext(props);
```

#### Main.java

```
SpeakerRemote speaker = (SpeakerRemote) context.lookup("ejb:myapp/myejbmodule/SpeakerBean!test.SpeakerRemote);
System.out.println( speaker.sayAPhrase( "Hello, World!" ) )
```

Comment: I've done described in 1st your approach. But it's still not working. I guess why. I looked throught jboss-client.jar and didn't find "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" in it. I found only "org.jboss.naming.(NamingContextFactory | BridgeNamingContextFactory | HttpNamingContextFactory | and others)" Может у меня jar-ник не тот?

Comment: There are not your classes in my file. If you use maven, try add dependensy org.jboss.as.jboss-as-ejb-client-bom. Look for in this example https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/master/ejb-remote.

Comment: I'd looked throught this example before you gave me. It is described jboss.docs. But I suppose, you didn't get what I'd said. Have a look at "RemoteCalculator" class "lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator" method. There is used this construction: jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming")
Tell me pls, where "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" is located? Where does JVM (or smth else) get it form? I suspect, it is taken from jboss-client.jar. If it is true, I see it. But going throught this dir, I can't find it in my jbosss-clinet.jar
You see it?

Comment: Yes, I see org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory in jboss-client.jar.

Comment: Ok, I found it too. But listen, tell me, how can I use RemoteCalculator in my program? Shell I inject something?
There are described EJB and EJB-Client. They are assembled into pom-file. I understand it. But how can I execute pom-project? I may only deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
package test;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.RemoteBinding;  

@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="SpeakerBean/remote")
public class SpeakerBean implements SpeakerRemote {
@Override
 public String sayAPhrase( String phrase ){
     return "Speaker Service:\t" + phrase;
}
}
```

Comment: yes, I am trying to do it, but I still hav no success. I added:jboss-ejb3-ext-api:1.1.1.jar to my libs and added dependency to pom.xml.After compiling I've got: "Failure to find org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-build:pom:1.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"

Comment: ping me the previous exception with line number

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpeakerService: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:SpeakerService:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-ext-api:jar:1.1.1 -> org.jboss.metadata:jboss-metadata:jar:1.0.0.CR16: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.metadata:jboss-metadata:jar:1.0.0.CR16: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.metadata:jboss-metadata:pom:1.0.0.CR16 from/to jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2)   But I am trying to download another artefactId

Comment: I am trying to use this (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.ejb3/jboss-ejb3-ext-api/2.1.0) archetype, but there is no any Local/RemoteBinding.class :( What shell I do?